# Modal Popup working in codepen but not on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

please can you assist - my modal popup works in codepen however when I migrate over to my website the modal popup doesn't work

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s3-online.com/images/2018/10/15/placeit.png" alt="brain">
  <span class='pulse-button'/></span>
  <span class='pulse-button2'></span>
  <span class='pulse-button3'></span>
  <span class='pulse-button4'></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

/* Container needed to position the button. Adjust the width as needed */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Make the image responsive */
.container img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}

/* Style the button and place it in the middle of the container/image */
.pulse-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: navy;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.pulse-button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

.pulse-button2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -115px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: navy;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.pulse-button2:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

.pulse-button3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 260px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: navy;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.pulse-button3:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

.pulse-button4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: navy;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, .5);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.5s infinite;
}

.pulse-button4:hover {
  -webkit-animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
  }
  70% {
    @include transform(scale(1));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
    100% {
    @include transform(scale(.9));
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(#5a99d4, 0);
  }
}

.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 40px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Define data for popup
var data = [
  {
    photo_img: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81UYaJFVjCL._SY450_.jpg", // Prefix "_img" is special. With it Magnific Popup finds an  element "photo" and replaces it completely with image tag.
    }
];


// Initialize popup 
$('.pulse-button').magnificPopup({
      key: 'image-popup',
      items: data,
      type: 'inline',
      inline: {
        // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
        markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
 '<div class="mfp-photo"></div>'+
            '</div>'
            }
        });

// Define data for popup
var data = [
  {
    photo_img: "https://s3-online.com/images/2018/10/13/ai-pic-2.jpg", // Prefix "_img" is special. With it Magnific Popup finds an  element "photo" and replaces it completely with image tag.
    }
];


// Initialize popup 
$('.pulse-button2').magnificPopup({
      key: 'image-popup',
      items: data,
      type: 'inline',
      inline: {
        // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
        markup: '<div class="white-popup"><div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
 '<div class="mfp-photo"></div>'+
            '</div>'
            }
        });
```

The pulse buttons etc all works, however, the modal popup does not open on my website at all. Works perfectly on codepen - link: [https://codepen.io/DrSmith69/pen/LgOPpO](http://Codepen%20link)

Link on website where it doesn't work: [https://s3-online.com/](http://Website%20link)

Comment: Let me see if I got this straight: you're providing the link from where it works and ask why it doesn't work someplace else, right? How do you suggest we figure that out, if we can't see how it fails and you don't provide any such info?

Comment: Updated question with link to website, it is 3/4 down the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load jQuery over `http`, which is blocked by your browser, since your website is on `https`. Change the jQuery dependency to

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

... and it will work.

Comment: legend! that was a huge blonde moment

Comment: Opening console (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + I) might help getting this type of errors, @D.

Comment: Thanks very much!